# Magento 2 How to Store Contact us form in Database

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, User Enter Details in Magento **Contact form** and it should be stored in **Database** is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your module create a Model Contact to store in database. Then override the Post.php .try this code I hope it will work.

```
public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->isPostRequest()) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
    }
    try {
        $request = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('\Test\Contact\Model\Contact');
        $model->setName($request['name']);   
        $model->setEmail($request['email']); 
        $model->setTelephone($request['telephone']);
        $model->setMessage($request['comment']); 
        $model->save(); 
        $this->sendEmail($this->validatedParams());
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
             __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
         );
         $this->dataPersistor->clear('contact_us');

    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('\Test\Contact\Model\Contact');
        print_r($model);
        die;
        $this->logger->critical($e);
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
            __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
        );
        $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('contact/index');
}
```

Comment: can you share your model file please if it is possible

Comment: Can you please share the model file for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new module that create new `contacts` table using setup script. Also Create `Model`, `ResourceModel` and `Collection` class for `contacts` table in your new module.

Next create `etc/di.xml` file in your module and change prefenrence for contacts post controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="Stack\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" />
</config>
```

and Copy `Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post` Controller in your module on the below path and update class as per your module.

```
app/code/Stack/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php
```

You can write Data Save code for `contacts` model in your module `Post` Controller.

Comment: Error in this line $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Test/Contact/Model/Contact');                                                                            
 // Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Test/Contact/Model/Contact does not exist

Comment: in post controller i faced this error how to rectify