# how to save contact form in magento2 database

Tags: magento2.3, contact-form

i am very new to magento 2 and need to save in a database the details that users enter in the magento 2 contact form

but I didn't make it, can someone help me?

Comment: you create model file and put this code https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/229288/85907

Comment: I already did, but it didn't work out.